# MacBook Pro dies once or twice per day

Tags: macbook

My MacBook Pro (middle 2009)  dies once or twice per day, with the screen picture stopped, and all the keys don't work, including the Caps Lock key. So I can only force-shutdown it using the power button.

- 2013.4.25 Plugged in 8G memory (2 × 4G)
- 2013.4.28 Repaired the disk permissions
- 2013.4.29 Fell from chair (1 foot high), and then got stuck three times in the afternoon.
- 2013.4.30 I had a test. Opened my MacBook, keeping no apps running. And it died ten minutes later.
- 2013.5.2 13:58:12 Got stuck when I was using it, and the screen flashed red.
- 2013.5.3 
  1.Verified the disk using "Disk Utility" and  everything is OK. But the "Apple Call services" man told to me,"it's just seems OK, not certainly OK".  -__-|||... 
  2.The task manager shows the Dropbox is keeping using the CPU & Disk. So I quited Dropbox, which leads a miracle (^o^)/~, the "dies" phenomenon didn't come out all day along.
- In the end, I came to  one of "Apple Authorized Service Providers". And paid for a socalled "professional" test.
  Finally,they told me the the hard disk is ok, but there may be some trouble in the logic board which will cause wrong when the temperature rise .  Yes, the answer is maybe..... 
  Their solution  is to replace a new logic board, which will cost lot that I would rather buy a new one .

Comment: Well, since it fell from the chair I'd just say it will be caused by that – some kind of mechanical failure with either the hard disk or the logic board. I'd try having it repaired. Are you sure the chair was just 1 inch high? Did you mean 1 foot?

Comment: @slhck Thx! That was very thoughtful of you. It's 1 foot as you  mentioned.

Comment: So, what is the question, now that Dropbox is disabled? And what if you put the old memory back in? (And, small chance, but: my sister had freeze problems caused by Spotify on a OS X 10.6 machine. Spotify does not support 10.6 anymore, but still an automatic update was performed, making her Mac very unstable. So: automatic software updates can be the start of troubles.)